Help with logical operator
I have a model with different days $t\in T$ and different shifts $k\in ${ $k_1, k_2, k_3$}. I now want to write the following sentence with logic operators.
"For all $t\in ${$1,...,T-1$}, if shift $k_2$ applies on day $t$, then only $k_2$ or $k_3$ can apply on day $t+1$."
That would be my attempt so far, but it neglects the $t$ and $+1$ part.:
$$\forall t \in \{1,\ldots,T-1\}: k_2(t) \rightarrow k_2(t+1) \lor k_3(t+1)
$$
How would it be correct?

Make $k$ a a doubly indexed variable, for instance, $k_{t,s}$, where $t$ is the day and $s$ is the shift. Now you should be able to express the desired logic. Your notation and choice of letters is a little squirrelly, so I will let you fix that.

I just did that

I assume your notation here is that $k_2(t)$ is a logical entity (true if shift $k_2$ applies on day $t$, false if not). Read that way, your implication statement is correct if the model specifies that only one shift can apply on any day.

Thank you for your answer. Would this also hold if no shift could be applied on the next day?

No. In that case you would need something like $k_2(t+1) \vee k_2(t+1) \vee k_0(t+1)$ on the right (where $k_0(s)$ is true if no shift applies on day $s$). Alternatively, you could frame it as $$k_{2}(t)\implies\neg\bigvee_{i\notin\left{ 2,3\right} }k_{i}(t+1),$$ which says that if $k_2$ applies on day $t$ then no shift outside of $k_2$ or $k_3$ can apply on day $t+1.$ Having no shift at all on $t+1$ would satisfy this.
